# How do I change opacity of title bars in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: unity, compiz, window-manager, titlebar, transparency

I've heard that unity is using it's own window manager so that I can't change the opacity using CompizConfig...

But is there an alternative? I already made the main title bar transparant together with the sidebar. The only that's left is the title bar of not-maximized windows.

Thank you.